# Export Access Query WITHOUT Formatting

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-csv

Relatively simple, but I can't seem to work it out. I want to export a query from access into a `.csv` (tab or comma delimited). When I do it manually through the wizard it works fine. But when I do it via vba, it comes complete with dash formatting that looks like the borders in the table!

I tried two methods and got the same results

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Qry_GRADE", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)",_
 "grade.csv", True, *ExportSpec*, , acExportQualityScreen
```

I used it with or without "ExportSpec", which is a specification I created when exporting manually.

This is the second method:

```
Dim testSQL As String
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

    testSQL = "SELECT * FROM Qry_Grade"
    Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("tmpExport", testSQL)
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport",_
         "C:\Users\Databoe\Documents\KidsTV\grade.csv"
    db.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport"
```

[This is a solution](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=152949) I've found which seems like overkill

And this is what the output looks like:

[image: screenshot exported query]

You can see it's not actually split any of the columns when opening the file in excel and that every second line is just a string of "-"'s

Comment: If you mean writing the file directly is "overkill" it is not. It's the only method where you have 100% control of the output. And once created, it just works with zero issues. Highly recommended.

Comment: I get your point, but given that there is a wizard within access that allows for exporting that works, surely there is a vba method that replicates this? Or am I just naively trusting that MS would implement such a function!?

Comment: To be honest, I can't recall. But years ago, when creating export routines for six different receivers with all kinds of headers, formatting, special handling of empty fields, etc., I gave up and wrote the routines myself. It takes a little to get started, but it is quite straightforward really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, myQueryName, myExportFileName, True` for direct excel file export.

I tried your approaches, but I only get formated text with your first try `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Qry_GRADE", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)",_
 "grade.csv", True, *ExportSpec*, , acExportQualityScreen` which is as expected because it's a text export not csv.

With your second method I always get an excel compatible result. Maybe you have an error trap that hides an error and the first `grade.csv` is not overwritten. Use a different filename for the second method to prevent that.

Found a second trap. You don't specify full file path in first method, but in second. If `C:\Users\Databoe\Documents\KidsTV` is not your default document path, you have 2 `grade.csv` in different folders, but you maybe think that you only have one that gets overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, this sort of solved the problem. I exported as excel, as in your first suggestion. Then opened the excel file and saved as csv (as I needed that format over "acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9" ).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem myself, and found a great work around. It doesn't save as a .csv, but you can save as a comma delimited .txt file.

- Use the export wizard on the External Data tab to export your query as a .txt file without formatting.
- Once the file is exported you get a dialogue box asking if you want to save export steps. Click the box and save the export.
- There is an action available in the Macro wizard called "Run Saved Import/Export." Select this action and choose your saved export from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Very frustrating that even now I cant seem to make Access export a simple csv file.  I do not know why they think I need pretty formatting.  Try this:  open Excel, Click Get Data, From Database, From MicroSoft Access Database.  Select the Access Database you wish to export from.  Select the table/query we want saved as an csv.  This will set up a link to this table.  Once imported, save the Excel file to an csv file.